# Select from "this sheet" to the end in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a report in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

- The finishing step is to select a large proportion of the sheets (all the ones to the right of the "Cover" page including the cover itself) and print them to PDF.
- The list of sheets can vary.

I'm currently doing this manually, but it seems the sort of thing that can be automated if you know the correct command.

Is it possible to do something along the following line?

```
Sheets(Array(Sheets("Cover")..Sheets(Worksheets.Count())).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-liner for this.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim i As Long, fnd As Boolean

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            If .Name = "Cover" Then
                fnd = True
                .Select
            Else
                If fnd Then .Select False
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one-line if you feed an array of sheet positions in, ie.e

```
Sheets(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=ROW(" & Sheets("Cover").Index & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Index & ")"))).Select
```

**how it works**

1. If `Cover` was sheet position 12 and there were 20 sheets in total  then
   `("=ROW(" & Sheets("Cover").Index & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Index & ")")))` equates to
   `"=ROW("12:20")`
2. `Application.Evaluate` produces a 2D array containg {12,13,14 ... 20}
3. `Application.Transpose` coverts this to a 1D array which had be handled by `Sheets(1D Array).Select`